# Do I have to set same batch size for training, validation and testing?

Tags: deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I was performing segmentation task and have set my batchsize to 16 for all train, validation and inferencing. In my observation, I got better result in inferencing when setting batch size to 1. How should I decide the correct size for these three or they will have to be of same size?

Comment: Can you give some code examples on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is your problem, what is your target and how are good your data. There isn't a correct number, but [here](https://www.v7labs.com/blog/train-validation-test-set) you can find some helps.